# error while concatenating multiple pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

i have 10 csv files with number of rows on each file close to 1 million. I have a for loop which iterates over filenames and creates a dataframe and concats the result.

```
for file in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv('file',sep=',', encoding='utf-8', dtype='object') 
    print (df)
    concatenated_df  = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

I am gettomg Memory Error and concat statement is failing intermittently. 
Printing df is working fine. I have 32 GB RAM on my desktop. Is there a better way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Store them into data base chunk by  chunk

Comment: your concatenation statement isn't doing what you expect. you want to store all of the data frames in a list and and then `concat` outside of your loop

Comment: i tried using list_ = [] outside the loop and then appending to the list list_.append(df) inside the loop. then outside the loop i have frame = pd.concat(list_) but looks like concat is failing due to # CHECK DTYPE? and  MemoryError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 32GB is enough memory to deal with the data you have. Assuming, all the files have same number of columns, try this one liner:

```
concatenated_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(df, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', dtype='object') for df in filenames])
```

Comment: i am getting following error when i try your solution : TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: Thanks Manish. I am not getting the TypeError now but i am still getting MemoryError.

Comment: @Sun Why do you want to concat the files? Is there some specific operation you want to do?